# how to extrude diagonally with precision?

Tags: modeling

i am trying to extrude these vertices diagonally but with precision, just like when extrude along x or z etc... but how could it be done with the same precision when extruded along an axis? instead of going horizontally or vertically , i want to do it diagonally but i dont know how to do it

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've made your first extrusion, select the edge, open the *Transform Orientations* panel, click on the "+" button in order to create a new orientation that is aligned with your edge. Keep this new orientation selected in the panel and extrude along Y (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>).

[image]

In 2.79, at the bottom of the *N* panel (on the right of your 3D view, activate with <kbd>N</kbd>) > *Transform Orientations*, click on the "+" button:

[image]

Now the custom orientation is part of the *Transform Orientations* panel. After <kbd>E</kbd> for extrusion you'll need to press <kbd>y</kbd> twice though:

[image]

Comment: is such option available in blender 2.79?

Comment: @ Albert Paige Turner, yes, please check my edit

Comment: Thank you so much! :)!!